# What is a "primary expression"?

Tags: parsing, powershell

In the PowerShell Language Specification, the grammar has a term called "Primary Expression".

```
primary-expression:
    value
    member-access
    element-access
    invocation-expression
    post-increment-expression
    post-decrement-expression
```

Semantically, what is a primary expression intended to describe?

Comment: I think it is something which can be referred in an expression using '_$'.

Comment: looks like the prioritized testing paths for deciding on whether the primary-expression should be treated as a command or an expression, no?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it there are two parts to this:

1. Formal grammars break up things like expressions so operator precedence is implicit.

   Eg. if the grammar had

   ```
   expression:
     value
     expression * expression
     expression + expression
     …
   ```

   There would need to be a separate mechanism to define `*` as having higher precedence than `+`. This
   becomes significant when using tools to directly transform the grammar into a tokeniser/parser.<sup>1</sup>
2. There are so many different specific rules (consider the number of operators in PowerShell) that using fewer rules would be harder to understand because each rule would be so long.

---

<sup>1</sup> I suspect this is not the case with PowerShell because it is highly context sensitive (express vs command mode, and then consider calling non-inbuilt executables). But such grammars across languages tend to have a lot in common, so style can also be carried over (don't re-invent the wheel).

Answer (score 1):

My understaning of it is that an expression is an arrangement of commands/arguments and/or operators/operands that, taken together will execute and effect an action or produce a result (even if it's $null) than can be assigned to a variable or send down the pipeline.  The term "primary expression" is used to differentiate the whole expression from any sub-expressions $() that may be contained within it.

Answer (score 1):

My very limited experience says that primary refers to expressions (or sub-expressions) that can't be parsed in more than one way, regardless of precedence or associativity.  They have enough syntactic anchors that they are really non-negotiable--ID '(' ID ')' for example, can only match that.  The parens make it guaranteed, and there are no operators to allow for any decision on precedence.

In matching an expression tree, it's common to have a set of these sub-expressions under a "primary_expr" rule.  Any sub-expressions can be matched any way you like because they're all absolutely determined by syntax.  Everything after that will have to be ordered carefully in the grammar to guarantee correct precedence and associativity.

There's some support for this interpretation [here](http://www.craftinginterpreters.com/parsing-expressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

think $(  lots of statements )  would be like a complex expression
and in powershell most things can be an expression like
$a = if ($y) { 1 } else { 2}
so primary expression is likely the lowest common denominator of classic expressions
a single thing that returns a value
whether an explicit value, calling something.. getting a variable, or a property from a variable $x.y or the result of increment operation $z++
but even a simple math "expression" wouldn't match this  4 +2 + (3 / 4 ) , that would be more of a complex expression.

So I was thinking of the WHY behind it, and at first it was mentioned that it could be to help determine command/expression mode, but with investigation that wasn't it. Then i thought maybe it was what could be passed in command mode as an argument explicitly, but thats not it, because if you pass $x++ as a parameter to a cmdlet you get a string.

I think its probably just the lowest common denominator of expressions, a building block, so the next question is what other expressions does the grammar contain, and where is this one used?